# JSONP & Angular Adding Extra Empty data

Tags: php, angularjs, jsonp

Everything is working fine however i'm getting an extra 5 lines of empty data when there is no other data:

Example:

```
Sat, Apr 25 2015 Madison Square Garden, New York, New York, USA
Wladimir Klitschko 63 vs Bryant Jennings 19
vs
vs
vs
vs
vs
Sat, May 09 2015 Minute Maid Park, Houston, Texas, USA
James Kirkland 32 vs Saul Alvarez 44
vs
vs
vs
vs
vs
```

My JS:

```
function WidgetCtrl($scope, $http) {
$scope.items = [];
$http.jsonp("http:/domain.com/schedule?callback=JSON_CALLBACK").success(function(data) 
{
    $scope.items = data;
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.status = status;
});
}
```

index.html

```
<div id="widget-content" ng-controller="WidgetCtrl">      
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
{{item.searchdate}} {{item.event_place}}
<div class="widget-list">
<div ng-repeat="name in item">
{{name.boxer1_name}} {{name.boxer1_w}} vs {{name.boxer2_name}}                {{name.boxer2_w}}
</div>         
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

JSON:

```
[  
  {  
    "event_id":"1821",
    "searchdate":"Sat, Apr 25 2015",
    "event_place":"Madison Square Garden, New York, New York, USA",
    "networks":"TV: HBO Boxing",
    "time":"Time: 9pm Et",
    "0":{  
      "match_id":"5068",
      "match_name":"Heavyweight",
      "mainevent":"main",
      "body":"",
      "boxer1_id":"7",
      "boxer1_name":"Wladimir Klitschko",
      "boxer1_w":"63",
      "boxer1_l":"3",
      "boxer1_d":"0",
      "boxer1_ko":"53",
      "boxer2_id":"2780",
      "boxer2_name":"Bryant Jennings",
      "boxer2_w":"19",
      "boxer2_l":"0",
      "boxer2_d":"0",
      "boxer2_ko":"10"
    }
  },
  {  
    "event_id":"1853",
    "searchdate":"Sat, May 09 2015",
    "event_place":"Minute Maid Park, Houston, Texas, USA",
    "networks":"TV: HBO",
    "time":"Time: 9pm ET",
    "0":{  
      "match_id":"5127",
      "match_name":"super welterweight",
      "mainevent":"main",
      "body":"",
      "boxer1_id":"233",
      "boxer1_name":"James Kirkland",
      "boxer1_w":"32",
      "boxer1_l":"1",
      "boxer1_d":"0",
      "boxer1_ko":"28",
      "boxer2_id":"1336",
      "boxer2_name":"Saul Alvarez",
      "boxer2_w":"44",
      "boxer2_l":"1",
      "boxer2_d":"1",
      "boxer2_ko":"31"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: There isn't enough detail and data here to help.  The JSON data posted is clearly not the data providing the example so it's not real helpful. A plnkr that reproduces what is happening would be most helpful.

Comment: The json data posted is the data providing the example. I guarantee it.

Comment: When I looked the first time there were 8 boxers showing and the JSON data was a single line showing just 1 boxer, so the data above changed since first I looked at it.

Comment: Yes. I have two feeds, one is full fight card and other is just main event. Sorry. However its all the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is "name in item" in your second ng-repeat. It is simply going through the 6 pieces of data (event_id, searchdate, etc.) and the only one that it find boxer data in is the item called "0".  Based on your data you should use

```
      <ng-repeat="name in item.0">
```

because your boxer data is contained in item.o not in item.

Comment: I tried that, however what happens then.. I get the event details but no boxers and i get 16 items listed all blank.

Answer (score 0):

After three days I fixed the problem. I changed my JSON feed from "0" to "match". Thanks Scott. Somehow your answer helped me figure this out.